# How to use lists in new regex when the items have re.escape characters?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the List option in the new [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) library. The List works fine if the items in the list do not contain any re escape characters. But it doesn't work when there are re escape characters as shown below. What is the right way to use Lists in this case.

```
import regex as re

print('=====Test case0=====')
mys="|abcxyz |defblah"
l={re.escape('|abc'),re.escape('|def')}

p=re.compile(r'(?=\|abc|\|def)\|.+?(?:\b|$)')          #WORKS
print(p.findall(mys))

p=re.compile(r'(?=\L<l>)\|.+?(?:\b|$)',l=l)            #DOESN'T WORK
print(p.findall(mys))


print('=====Test case1=====')
mys="$abcxyz $defblah"
l={re.escape('$abc'),re.escape('$def')}

p=re.compile(r'(?=\$abc|\$def)\$.+?(?:\b|$)')          #WORKS
print(p.findall(mys))

p=re.compile(r'(?=\L<l>)\$.+?(?:\b|$)',l=l)            #DOESN'T WORK
print(p.findall(mys))

print('=====Test case2=====')
mys="abcxyz defblah"
l={re.escape('abc'),re.escape('def')}

p=re.compile(r'(?=abc|def).+?(?:\b|$)')               #WORKS
print(p.findall(mys))

p=re.compile(r'(?=\L<l>).+?(?:\b|$)',l=l)             #WORKS
print(p.findall(mys))
```

---

**output**

```
=====Test case0=====
['|abcxyz', '|defblah']
[]
=====Test case1=====
['$abcxyz', '$defblah']
[]
=====Test case2=====
['abcxyz', 'defblah']
['abcxyz', 'defblah']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because the strings you pass to `\L` are `re.escape`d by default, and when you pre-escape them, they get escaped twice.

Just use

```
l=['|abc','|def']
```

and then pass the `l` list to the `\L` operator.

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/UJCVY77556).

The documentation is a bit vague but this behavior is [hinted at](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/):

> `\L<name>` 
> There are occasions where you may want to include a list (actually, a set) of options in a regex.
>
> One way is to build the pattern like this:
>
> `>>> p = regex.compile(r"first|second|third|fourth|fifth")`
>
> but if the list is large, parsing the resulting regex can take considerable >time, and **care must also be taken that the strings are properly escaped if they contain any character that has a special meaning in a regex**, and that if there is a shorter string that occurs initially in a longer string that the longer string is listed before the shorter one, for example, “cats” before “cat”.
>
> The new alternative is to use a named list

Comment: [Another demo](http://rextester.com/JQT76672) showing that `re.escape` with `\L<name>` really double escapes the input.